# Installing Kibana X-Pack on mac os

Tags: node.js, macos, elasticsearch, kibana, xpack

I have installed X-Pack on ElasticSearch using

```
bin/elasticsearch-plugin install x-pack
```

When i am trying to install the plugin on Kibana with the same command

```
bin/kibana-plugin install x-pack
```

I am getting the following error

```
/usr/local/bin/node: bad option: --no-warnings
```

I understand that its somehow related to node.js but i can't figure out a way to move forward with the installation.

I appreciate any comments or thoughts regarding the issue.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you try to install x-pack for kibana ?

Comment: Yes. After i install the plugin for elasticsearch i proceed on the installation of X-pack for kibana and i get the error that i mentioned

Answer (score 2):

If you edit the kibana-plugin script, you can remove the --no-warnings option to get the plugin manager working

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Node to 6.9.4 LTS and was able to install plugins.

Use nvm to manage your version of node.js: https://github.com/creationix/nvm